# How can the function multIndepTest on the R package Copula work?

Tags: r, independence, copula

I'm preparing for the test of dynamic dependence using the copula package, so that I tried to test the independence among the time series of the sample.

The function `multIndeptest` from Copula package doesn't work despite my writing it in the normally correct form as following:

```
multIndepTest(Base3mod,d=5,m=1772,N=1000,alpha =0.05,verbose = interactive() )
```

where `Base3mod` is the data.frame Name , 5 is the data dimensions and `m` is the dimension of the 5 time series.

The error text posted is the following:

```
Error in multIndepTest(Base3mod, d = 5, m = 1772, N = 1000, alpha = 0.05,  : 
  m should be an integer greater than 2 and smaller than 1
```

Thank you for explaining to me the error cause.

Comment: "an integer greater than 2 and smaller than 1" suggests some major confusion somewhere, but I have no idea where.

Comment: `copula::multIndepTest` is a test for independence between subsets (random vectors) of your series (e.g. is $(X_1,X_2)$ independent of $(X_3,X_4)$?), the parameter `d` defines the partition into subsets (e.g. `c(2,2,1)`), and the parameter `m` sets the maximum number of subsets to test (e.g. if `m=2`, the test for independence between $(X_1,X_2)$, $(X_3, X_4)$ and $X_5$ is not performed). From my understanding you have 5 series only and aren't partitioning them into subsets of random vectors, so `m=1772` is an error. You are probably looking for `copula::indepTest` instead.

Comment: thank you for your answers